# Error in httpd.conf. Can't locate API module structure `php5_module'

Tags: php, httpd.conf

I've recently installed phc, the php compiler.  I started out installing LAMP from source with --enable-so for Apache and --enable-embed for PHP5 (among other options these are most relevant to the installation and later configuration).

When I finished installing I realized phc does not yet support PHP5.3 so I uninstalled it and installed PHP5.2.  phc works fine now, as does the PHP client application for the commandline.  Apache seems to be running fine, too, when I comment out line 193 (see below).  It just doesn't parse PHP.

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 193 of /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `php5_module' in file /usr/local/lib/libphp5.so: /usr/local/lib/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: php5_module
```

When I check my version of PHP from the terminal I get the expected output (5.2):

```
[root@localhost conf]# php -v
PHP 5.2.14 (cli) (built: Sep  7 2010 22:50:25) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

I made sure to move the libphp5.so file from the folder where I built php5.2 (/usr/local/src/php-5.2.14) to /usr/local/lib.  I also moved php.ini to /usr/local/lib.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Shouldn't libphp5.so be in Apache's modules folder?

Comment: @NullUserException hey again!  I tried copying it to /etc/apache2/modules (the modules folder for apache) and changing security settings using chcon -t textrel_shlib_t '/etc/apache2/modules/libphp5.so' and changing line 193 to reflect the change...  I get the same error with the directory changed to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK!

Apparently when you configure PHP it's important to include the line specifying wehre to find apxs for the proper installation:

```
--with-apxs2=/etc/apache2/bin/apxs
```

I did this and the problem vanished :)